# Application Cache or JSON

Tags: json, caching, asp-classic

I'm working on a classic asp jscript application. I want to cache a collection of variable in the applications cache (2000 values), would it be better to create a JSON object to store the values and store it in the Application cache, or store each value in the Application cache individually? JSON has the drawback of requiring parsing. I'm not sure of the limitations of the Application cache in classic asp.

There is also the middle ground where I could sort the collection, and store several smaller JSON objects reducing the cost of parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my findings so far:
Creating a single object has a lot of overhead parsing.

Single 2500 value object: 44.22ms

25x 100 values objects: 2.34ms

50x 50 values objects: 1.41ms

2500 x 1 value object: 0.46ms

I'm sure there is some unaccounted for overhead in using 2500 items of Application cache.